# Token authorisation gets error 400 Only in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, response

I implemented an OAuth login flow that works perfectly when running in a local environment in my ASP.Net application.

However, when I publish my api on an external server there a strange behaviour that is occuring.

Heres what's happening, I publish the api, login on my application with my phone and everything seems good. If I close the app for 20 minutes and open it back everything loads back and my access is still granted. Now if I close the app for an hour and try to open it back, I get error 400. Not even 401 for unauthorized access.

What I checked :

1. I did check if maybe the cache of the app was getting cleared, but negative, the token is still in memory and successfully being sent.
2. Maybe my token had a short expiry date but as you can see in the settings its 12 hours

   ```
   OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = 
      new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
   {
       AllowInsecureHttp = true,
       TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
       AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12),
       Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
       RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
   };
   ```
3. I even implemented a refresh token system, so if the token is invalid It refreshes the token, again, it works in dev. But in production, it only works for 20 mins and then i get error 400.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the caching of the server, I guess the context is being cleared.

So My question is : Has anyone get a situation similar to this one and what was the solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  We are getting 400's *sometimes* - it is not consistent and, like you, only in production which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: I figured out my issue which may or may not help you.  I was storing the protected ticket in the database but sometime the protected ticket was larger than the field defined in the database.  When I tried to refresh one of those the decryption of the protected ticket failed and I got 400.  Made the field bigger, fixed the issue.